# How to unallocate a partition in Ubuntu using GPARTED?

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I want to unallocate a partition so that I can merge it with another partition using GParted. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick the "un mount" option (if the partition is mounted) and then pick the "delete" option in gparted. Mind that this is permanent and will remove anything on that partition. The partition will then be shown as "unallocated" ready to be added to any partition next to it.

Extra remark: it is best to not do this with a live gparted session but from Ubuntu itself as you need to unmount that partition and this will prevent you from unmounting your systems partition. Be sure to triple check you pick the correct partition and do make a backup of all your personal data.